# redirection after successful login does not work with nextauth.js

Tags: reactjs, next.js, next.js13, next-auth

I'm building a next.js application and I'm currently adding the authentication layer based on the following [documentation](https://nextjs.org/learn/dashboard-app/adding-authentication)

This is my auth configuration :

- myApp/auth.ts

```
import { sql } from "@vercel/postgres"
import bcrypt from "bcrypt"
import type { User } from "lib/definitions"
import NextAuth from "next-auth"
import Credentials from "next-auth/providers/credentials"
import { z } from "zod"

import { authConfig } from "./auth.config"

export const { auth, signIn, signOut } = NextAuth({
  ...authConfig,
  providers: [
    Credentials({
      async authorize(credentials) {
        const parsedCredentials = z
          .object({ email: z.string().email(), password: z.string().min(6) })
          .safeParse(credentials)

        if (parsedCredentials.success) {
          const { email, password } = parsedCredentials.data
          const user = await getUser(email)
          if (!user) {
            return null
          }
          const passwordsMatch = await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password)

          if (passwordsMatch) {
            return user
          }
        }

        return null
      },
    }),
  ],
})
```

- myApp/auth.config.ts

```
import type { NextAuthConfig } from "next-auth"

export const authConfig = {
  pages: {
    signIn: "/signIn",
  },
  callbacks: {
    authorized({ auth, request: { nextUrl } }) {
      return !!auth?.user
    },
  },
  providers: [],
} satisfies NextAuthConfig
```

- myApp/middleware.ts

```
import NextAuth from 'next-auth';
import { authConfig } from './auth.config';
 
export default NextAuth(authConfig).auth;
 
export const config = {
  // https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/middleware#matcher
  matcher: ['/((?!api|_next/static|_next/image|.*\\.png$).*)'],
};
```

I have a signIn form :

- myApp/app/signIn/page.tsx

```
"use client"

import { useFormState } from "react-dom"
import { Button } from "@/registry/new-york/ui/button"
import { Input } from "@/registry/new-york/ui/input"
import { signIn } from "../lib/actions"
import { ActionResult } from "../sharedTypes"

export function SignInForm() {
  const [result, action] = useFormState<ActionResult | undefined, FormData>(
    signIn,
    undefined
  )
  return (
    <form action={action}>
      <div className="grid gap-4">
        <div>
          <Input id="email" placeholder="Email" type="email" name="email" />
        </div>
        <div>
          <Input
            id="password"
            placeholder="Password"
            type="password"
            name="password"
          />
        </div>

        <Button>Sign in</Button>
        <div
          className="flex h-8 items-end space-x-1"
          aria-live="polite"
          aria-atomic="true"
        >
          {result?.errorMessage && (
            <>
              <p className="text-sm text-red-500">{result.errorMessage}</p>
            </>
          )}
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  )
}
```

And this is the server action called by the form :

```
"use server"

import { signIn as signInAuth } from "@/auth"
import { AuthError } from "next-auth"

import { ActionResult } from "../sharedTypes"

export async function signIn(
  prevState: ActionResult | undefined,
  formData: FormData
): Promise<ActionResult | undefined> {
  try {
    await signInAuth("credentials", formData)
  } catch (error) {
    if (error instanceof AuthError) {
      if (error.type === "CredentialsSignin") {
        return { errorMessage: "Invalid credentials" }
      }
      return { errorMessage: "Something went wrong" }
    }
    throw error
  }
}
```

When I go to **http://localhost:3001** without being already connected, everything works well and I'm redirected to the signIn page, my url becomes **http://localhost:3001/signIn?callbackUrl=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3001%2F**

Then I submit my valid credentials, a valid cookie is created and stored in my browser but instead of being redirected to the callbackUrl **http://localhost:3001**, I'm being redirected to the same current url **http://localhost:3001/signIn?callbackUrl=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3001%2F**, its like the callbackUrl has no interest.

Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 0):

If I remember correctly, you need to send the `callbackUrl` as parameter to the signIn function call like https://next-auth.js.org/getting-started/client#specifying-a-callbackurl (I know, not intuitiv when you already get it in the URL)

You could do something like:

```
    const searchParams = useSearchParams()
    const callbackUrl = searchParams.get('callbackUrl')
    // and add it to the form maybe as hidden field like
    return (
      <form action={action}>
        <Input id="callbackUrl" type="hidden" name="callbackUrl" value={callbackUrl} />
        <div className="grid gap-4">
          <div>
            <Input id="email" placeholder="Email" type="email" name="email" />
          </div>
          // rest of form here...
        </div>
      </form>
    )
```

in your client component

Comment: I was actually able to make it work by combining your suggestion and also update my signin method to add 2 parameters in addition to email/pwd, that are redirectTo:callbackUrl and redirect:true